# Parsing CSV file into Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, csv

I am looking to put the contents of a csv file into a dictionary:

```
public IDictionary<string, string> allContracts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

I am wondering how to do this as I have tried to find ways to use a csv parser however cannot find an effective method. I would like the code to run within:

```
public void CheckAvailability()
    {
       //this runs following a click even in a different section of my code

    }
```

Below is some sample data from the csv file I am looking to manipulate:

```
Vehicle ID,Customer ID,Booked Date,Booked_date_week_number,Number of Days Booked,BookingStatus
    135,CU1,1-Jul-19,27,0,Booked
    71,CU2,1-Jul-19,27,0,Booked
    73,CU3,1-Jul-19,27,0,Booked
    93,CU4,1-Jul-19,27,0,Booked
    137,CU5,1-Jul-19,27,0,Booked
    24,CU6,1-Jul-19,27,0,Booked
```

As you can see the column names are also included in the csv file, this is not an issue and is actually fundamental for the program I am creating.

Also please note I think I need to use a csv parser as the files being used are bigger than what's shown here, and so I don't want to encounter memory issues.

Comment: You need to include exactly _what_ you want in your dictionary. Which field do you want to use as the key? Which one(s) do you want to use for the value?

Comment: In general, CSV data can be more complex than your sample. For example, if a cell of the CSV contains a comma, the cell must be quoted. If you have a quote in a quoted cell, the quote must be escaped by doubling it. Example: "John ""Smitty"" Smith, Jr". For this reason, I suggest using a library to parse your data such as the popular CsvHelper. It is straightforward to use with good examples on the website.

Comment: A few things. 1) The size of the CSV file is not related to using a CSV parser, but more related to how big the file actually is and if it can be maintained directly in memory after being parsed. If it can fit into memory, then you are in for more complexity. 2) Why do you want to use a Dictionary, are one of the columns in the spreadsheet expected to be the key and directly lookup performance is critical.

Comment: ah! thank you @MattBurland . I am really new to C#. I would like the vehicle ID as the key and the rest as values. How do I specify this in the code?

Comment: @EricJ. I will look at CsvHelper and using a library. Thank you for taking the time to comment

Comment: @ahybertz Thank you. Yes the Vehicle ID will be used as the key. What do you suggest?

Comment: A CSV parser is recommended. It is unclear why you want a `Dictionary<string, string>`… the csv file appears to have six (6) fields. Is there some reason you do not simply make a Class where each field in the csv file is a property of that class? Depending on the CSV reader you choose, this class may simplify things quite a bit.

Comment: @JohnG this is originally what I wanted to do I have a class called contracts.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the dictionary?

Comment: @JohnG I am very new to C# and could not figure out how to utilize the class. In terms of how to open the file and parse the contents into the class. I think I just need to delete the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this differently, by making a class that represents each row and, if needed, creating a dictionary from that

```
void Main()
{
    // See https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\Bookings.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Booking>();
        var dictionary = records.ToDictionary(r => r.VehicleID, r => r);    
    }
}

public enum BookingStatus
{
    Booked,
    // TOOD: Add other statuses
}
public class Booking
{
    [Name("Vehicle ID")]
    public int VehicleID { get; set; }
    [Name("Customer ID")]
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    [Name("Booked Date")]
    public DateTime BookedDate { get; set; }
    [Name("Booked_date_week_number")]
    public int BookedDateWeekNumber { get; set; }
    [Name("Number of Days Booked")]
    public int NumberOfDaysBooked { get; set; }
    [Name("BookingStatus")]
    public BookingStatus BookingStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Note that using the Vehicle ID as the key in your dictionary fails if the same vehicle ID appears more than once in the CSV file. You may find it more useful to create an array or list, which you could then query as needed with Linq, e.g. replace the line that creates the dictionary

```
var dictionary = records.ToDictionary(r => r.VehicleID, r => r);
```

with

```
var csvData = records.ToArray();
```

then you can do things like

```
var bookingsForVehicle = csvData.Where(d => d.VehicleID == 42);
```

The reason to call a method like .ToArray() or .ToList() is to avoid enumerating the results multiple times, which would cause the file to be parsed multiple times.

Comment: I'm going to give this a go and will accept it once I get it working. Thank you for your perseverance with me.

Answer (score 2):

I maintain some libraries that can help with this: [Sylvan.Data.Csv and Sylvan.Data](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan). These libraries offer an API very similar to the CsvHelper library that Eric J. suggested. The main difference is that you don't need to manually map the column names assuming that the property names are a "PascalCase" conversion of the header in the CSV, which can be a marginal convenience. My data binder (the code behind `GetRecords<T>`) is `DbDataReader`-agnostic, so it can also be used with other data sources, such as a SqlServer result set, or my [Sylvan.Data.Excel](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan.Data.Excel)  library (see commented out lines below). These libraries are also the [fastest-in-class in the .NET ecosystem](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Benchmarks).

CsvHelper probably offers some capabilities that my libraries do not, but for direct mappings like this the code is nearly identical. Modified Eric J.s sample:

```
using Sylvan.Data;
using Sylvan.Data.Csv;
//using Sylvan.Data.Excel;

using (var data = CsvDataReader.Create("bookings.csv"))
//using (var data = ExcelDataReader.Create("bookings.xlsx"))
{
    var dictionary =
        data.GetRecords<Booking>()
        .ToDictionary(r => r.VehicleId, r => r);
}

public enum BookingStatus
{
    Booked,
    // TODO: Add other statuses
}

public class Booking
{
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime BookedDate { get; set; }
    public int BookedDateWeekNumber { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfDaysBooked { get; set; }
    public BookingStatus BookingStatus { get; set; }
}
```